# Spring framework ignores @scheduled Tag

Tags: multithreading, spring, annotations, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am working with Spring framework.

I had a `@Component` which extends thread.
In this Class I do something with JNI.(from now I will call it 'A')

Additionally, I have 2 Classes with `@Scheduled` annotation. 
(from now I will call these 'B' and 'C')

The problem occurs when I run this program. If 'A' works, others are ignored. The opposite case also works('B' and 'C' work, while 'A' does not) but things never work together.

I programmed like this way.

initializer bean. Below is part of root-context.xml.

```
<!-- this works automatically when was is loaded -->
<!-- And I put @Component in that class -->
<bean name="initializer" class="org.owls.init.Starter" init-method="start"/>
```

scheduled bean #1

```
@Component
class Schedule1 {
@Scheduled(cron="*/30 * * * * *")
public void doA(){
System.out.println("doA...");
}
}
```

scheduled bean #2 is same with scheduled bean #1, except cron expression.(its expression is `cron="0 * * * * *"`.)

How can I set bean priority or force to execute scheduled task?

Comment: Code can be wrong, because I did not copy and paste. original code is too complicated to post here already. Thanks

Comment: "These are work fine, When upper one does not work, but if that works it does not work at all." This is not clear at all. Try to edit your question to make it clear on where you have a problem.